# Fixing a loose screw in metal/aluminium sofa

Tags: furniture, aluminum

I have bought an outdoor sofa on vidaxl.com that is made of aluminium tubulars.

[image]

The problem is that the quality of the product is bad, enough bad that after a couple of people gently pushed their back on the sofa, the screws (which were already difficult to tighten) came out by themselves.

Here is a photo displaying a detail
[image: Details]

In order to fix the back to the seating, both have two holes which allow a screw with a washer to fit in. There is no room to fit a screw nut, as **there is no exit hole** for the screw.

[image: Detail]

My problem is that the screws won't grip, and will indefinitely turn clockwise.

I asked a local blacksmith to electrically solder the parts, but he said that with so thin layer of tubular structure (should be around 1mm to his intuition) his solder would definitely melt the structure.

I don't think that asking for a warranty repair/refund will be feasible as the seller is Chinese and may demand that I send the package to China etc.

So I am asking about how to repair such a thing, if I can do. I was considering soldering even if that means that I won't be able to unmount the sofa in the future.

The sofa is made of 5 pieces, all suffer similar problems but only one has detached so far. So while I find out if I can return the whole thing and get refund, I would really love to fix it once for good.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, furniture repair is off topic here.

Comment: Through-bolt, drill and tap for larger bolt, drill and install rivnut, ...

Comment: Could you provide a pic of the actual problem spot with more context than just some metal tubes and the joints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest repair would be to drill those holes straight though the tube.

Replace those screws with bolts and nuts that are long enough to go though both tubes.  Use flat washers to spread the tension on the tube a bit more.

Can get round head bolts and cap nuts to have smooth edges.